# $\text{V}(A|Y) = \text{V}(Y|A) \text{V}(Y)^{-1}\text{V}(A)$ using Bayes rule

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, estimation, gaussian

Given a Bayes rule for density functions,
\begin{align}
f(a|y) = \frac{f(y|a)}{f(y)}f(a)
\end{align}
where the joint distribution is Gaussian, I aim to conclude
\begin{align}
\text{V}(A|Y) = \text{V}(Y|A) \text{V}(Y)^{-1}\text{V}(A)
\end{align}
Is it straightforward? How can we show that for the vector case, i.e., each random variable is a random vector?

The motivation is the error estimate before and after observing a single measurement. In part, $A$ is the source and $Y$ is the new measurement.

**Update**: The formula above is correct ONLY when applying a determinant on both sides. Consider
\begin{align}
V(A|Y)&= V(A) - V(A)\text{Cov}(A,Y)^TV(Y)^{-1}\text{Cov}(A,Y)V(A)\\
&= (I - V(A)\text{Cov}(A,Y)^TV(Y)^{-1}\text{Cov}(A,Y))V(A)\\
&\stackrel{(a)}= (I + V(A)\text{Cov}(A,Y)^TV(Y|A)^{-1}\text{Cov}(A,Y))^{-1}V(A)
\end{align}
where in $(a)$ we define $Y \triangleq \text{Cov}(Y,A)A + Z$ with $Z\sim N(0,V(Y|A)),$ and use the Matrix Inversion Lemma. By taking a determinant on both sides we get
\begin{align}
\det V(A|Y)&= \det (I + V(A)\text{Cov}(A,Y)^TV(Y|A)^{-1}\text{Cov}(A,Y))^{-1}\det V(A)\\
&= \det V(Y|A)\det(V(Y|A) + \text{Cov}(A,Y) V(A)\text{Cov}(A,Y)^T)^{-1}\det V(A)
\end{align}

Comment: If $(A, X, Y)$ is jointly Gaussian, then there is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) for each of the the conditional covariances in your question (in terms of sub-matrices of the covariance matrix of $(A, X, Y)$). I think you will find that the conditional covariances will not have a relationship that mirrors the equation relating the densities.

Comment: Also, none of the factors you have are valid covariances. Covariances are comparisons of two random variables and should have the form:  $\mathsf{Cov}(\text{first-variable},\text{second-variable}\mid\text{list-of-conditioning-variables})$

Comment: @GrahamKemp It might make sense if each of $A$, $X$, and $Y$ are Gaussian vectors and the covariances refer to covariance matrices. But then the matrix multiplication doesn't make sense because the matrix sizes are wrong.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamKemp angryavian, I corrected the formula.